# Setting up a trigger to update one table from another table inside mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is this:

When CCT1 is updated, also update CCT2.

What Row? The row with the matching ID (CCT1 ID:16 = CCT2 ID:16)

```
CCT1: ’O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles.raffle_id’

CCT2: ’O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting.category_id’
```

From data entered into a specific column in CCT1:
‘O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles.raffle_start_date’

I’d like to update a specific column in CCT2:
‘O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting.raffle_dates_from’

Here's what I've got so far... I'm sure its not even close haha.

[image: Screenshot]

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `Update Raffle Ticket Pro` AFTER UPDATE ON `O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles`
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting
SET raffle_dates_from = O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles.raffle_start_date
WHERE O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting.category_id = O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles.raffle_name
```

Comment: In the trigger's query definition, replace both `O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles` references with `NEW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the old values before the UPDATE you get by using for example OLD.raffle_start_date

The updated Values you get by using for example NEW.raffle_start_date

```
CREATE 
    TRIGGER  `Update Raffle Ticket Pro`
 AFTER UPDATE ON `O1cUxE_jet_cct_raffles` FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting 
      SET raffle_dates_from = NEW.raffle_start_date 
      WHERE O1cUxE_rafflepro_tickets_setting.category_id = NEW.raffle_name
```

Comment: YES! This did it... Thanks so much for your help... Can't thank you enough!!